# 1990 VW passat b3 doesn't start, engine shuts down on gas

Tags: vw, passat

I got my passat b3 as a gift from my grandfather for getting drivers license.
A week ago, when I was about to go to the city with my passat which previously was just fine, the engine would not start at all. The following day car was working and I have driven about 50 kilometers. After that day same thing happened: 
I was trying to start the engine like 5-10 times. One time it would turn on but the engine was coughing and after I pressed on gas it would shut down immediately following with more engine coughing.

I though that it might be something with fuel filter and pump as they were changed 10 years ago.  So I changed fuel filter yesterday and tried to turn on the car. However same problem persisted. I could turn on the car in first time but after I presses on gas, engine immediately turned off.
Today I changed fuel pump and same thing happened. Engine started in first time following with shut down on gas press. After that I could't start it any more.

I am 100% sure that battery is charged and operating correctly.

VW Passat 1990 1.6 liter gasoline 53kw.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Measure voltage at the pump on the power and ground wires. Is there any voltage drop? Is there a check engine light on? Can you do a fuel pressure test? Can you do an injector balance test? You should also test the throttle position sensor.

Comment: I would start looking for huge metered vacuum leaks, like a split intake hose after the MAF.

Comment: Pump is working fine. I was also thinking about checking injector...

Comment: You'd really need a Bently manual and some diagnostic tools to tell for sure.  This sounds a lot like a crank position sensor issue that my mk3 Jetta had.  Would run fine until the car got hot and then wouldn't run or start.  There are several sensors that could be at fault.